# Offensive/spam downvote penalty

Tags: support, reputation, flagging, spam, offensive

I was wondering about a certain behavior of the reputation system.

Suppose that someone flags one of my post as offensive or spam. This immediately issues a $-1$ vote.

Does that vote come with the $-2$ reputation change? And if so, when the flag is dismissed as invalid/unhelpful, do the downvote (and/or the reputation) are get withdrawn?

I know that if the flag is accepted as helpful then the post is deleted and a $-100$ penalty is issued.

Comment: I actually thought your story about the seven virgins and a mule was amusing, plus it comes from an E.L.P. song I like (on Brain Salad Surgery), but I can see how people might have been offended.

Comment: Will, I'm extremely tired, so I might had a few minutes where I black out completely. But... what?

Comment: lyrics from this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yIFBpn7_uBQ which may or may not play for you... Emerson, Lake and Palmer, long song called Karn Evil 9. They are singing about a carnival with rare exhibits, including "Seven virgins and a mule, keep it cool, keep it cool." I was pretending you had written that as a post and been downvoted. Sorry for the confusion. Maybe I should stop these, we are some 11 or 12 hours apart by time zone.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-work suggests that the implicit down vote is only for the calculation of the post score, and does not affect the reputation.